# jQuery smoothness calendar CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar

I am using the jQuery-ui.css (smoothness) only for the calendar CSS. Does anyone know all the calendar CSS functions that I could just use from it? I don't want to have all this extra CSS on the page because it is giving me many issues when all I am trying to do is use the calendar...

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your JQuery CSS through Theme Roller and on [download](http://jqueryui.com/download/) only select the widget you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't recommend trying to rip out "just the calendar styles" from the jquery ui css (especially while you are still developing your application), because if you suddenly decide you want to use the `datePicker()`, or the `draggable()`, or anything else from jQuery UI, you will find yourself having to sort through all the css again trying to match things up, which would be a massive headache for you, and a lot of unnecessary work.

**So if you are absolutely sure that you don't need any styles for your other components**, and you are hoping to minimize your CSS files, then you can selectively download only the features you will need from the jquery-ui **[download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/)**, or if you need to design a custom theme first, before selecting only the feautres you will need, then you can start with the **[theme-roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)**, which will take you to a download page, allowing you to select only the features that you will need.

Notice how the download page lets you check (or uncheck) the features you need (or don't need), **this will result in a download that contains only the necessary CSS to run your selected features.**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With that said, if all you are hoping for is to remove all the clutter of the CSS from your main html file, then its just as simple as placing all the CSS into its own file, and then import the css into your html file. That way your page still responds to all the CSS, without it getting in the way of your HTML.

**To import a css file, just place this line of code within your `<head></head>` tags:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

**Or if the css is already on your page, just copy and paste the css into it's own file** called "jquery-ui.css", then you can import it into your page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
```

By convention, and good code-organization, many people place their stylesheets in a folder called "css", that keeps all your project's stylesheets in one place, so if you choose to follow this convention (recommended), your code would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
```

You will typically see code organized like this:

```
ProjectRootDirectory/
   images/
   css/
   js/
   index.html
   ...
```

Where index.html would access its images from the `images` folder, styles from the `css` folder and javascripts from the `js` folder

Hope this helps!